# Blacklisting port-scanner via iptables

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, iptables, port

I operate a VPN server and am having issues with DDoS attackers port-scanning my VPN for open ports to flood.  I need a rule that will blacklist them after they have contacted X ports in Y seconds, so if they DO find one of my open ports, the server will not reply to them.
All the other rules I have tried have done one or more of the following:
**Forced the VPN to send RST packets instead of dropping traffic to ports that have no services** *(I drop packets instead of refusing so port-scans take longer)*
**Did not correctly blacklist them from accessing my open ports**
**Added my open ports to the list of ports that will cause an IP to get blacklisted** *(I do NOT want the ports hosting services to have ANY chance of adding an IP to the blacklist. I do, however, want these ports to DROP traffic to BLACKLISTED IPs only)*
Example of solution: 1.1.1.1 is the attacker and 2.2.2.2 is my server. 2.2.2.2 has port 777 open

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:1 # dropped because i dont have a service on this port

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:13 # dropped because i dont have a service on this port

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:60 # dropped because i dont have a service on this port

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:14 # dropped because i dont have a service on this port

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:11 # dropped because i dont have a service on this port

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:17 # THIS will trigger the blacklist system, blocking ALL from 1.1.1.1 for 1 hour

1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2:777 # dropped because blacklist, regardless of the port being open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out by myself. These are the rules that work best for me:
`iptables -N LOGPSCAN
iptables -A LOGPSCAN -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 2000/hour -j RETURN
iptables -A LOGPSCAN -m limit --limit 200/hour -j LOG --log-prefix "DROPPED Port scan: "
iptables -A LOGPSCAN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j LOGPSCAN`
Because there is no reason (in my circumstance) for a single host to send SYN to 200 ports in one hour, we can stop replying to SYN from any host violating this policy for the rest of the hour :D
Note: You may have to increase or decrease the threshold depending on how many services your server is hosting.

Comment: Why one of them is 2000 and the other one 200?